# Cross Platform App with Localization

Tags: python, ruby, eclipse, netbeans, monodevelop

I am interested in developing a simple language learning (French, German, etc) desktop application to assist users in learning vocabulary by seeing and listening (via MP3 files) to words simultaneously.

I done some programming when I was younger and see this as a long term project to get back into programming by developing an application to help me with language learning that I can share with others.

In addition to helping English speakers learn other languages I would like the application to be localized so that the interface (and audio files) could be switched to assist others in learning English.

I am very open minded and have read about Eclipse, MonoDevelop & NetBeans to develop a cross platform GUI. I have also read a lot of good things about Ruby and Python so would be interested on any advice/recommendation on which combination of language and tools I should use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tcl/tk has excellent unicode support, and a very workable message catalog library. It's also highly portable to all major platforms (and several not-so-major platforms). In addition, you have the option of packaging your whole app up as a platform-dependent runtime (tclkit) and platform-independent application file (starkit), or combine the two into platform-specific single-file executables (starpack). In your case I'm guessing you might want a third file that is the audio for a specific language. So, you could have the main application and "language packages" that contain the message catalogs and .mp3 files for each language.

Since you mention Python as a tag, another choice would be Python with Tkinter, wxPython or pyGTK. Python's unicode support isn't as clean as Tcl's, though, and requires a little more work to support.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I had not considered Tcl/tk.

Would a simple app developed in Tcl/tk be possible to port to Android if I wished to do so later on?

Comment: AFAIK Tcl isn't supported on android. I think it's possible to use tcl by installing some additional packages to the android environment but the tk code has no chance of working.

Comment: Ok. Android is just an idea and not a major consideration.

I have found the following TCL information.

GUI:
I am following the tutorials on http://www.tkdocs.com/
This also looks interesting: http://www.satisoft.com/tcltk/gridplus2/

Translation: 
http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/msgcat.htm

Database:

I'm not sure how complex a database will need to be but I am interested to learn about Metakit. Do you have any other ideas about where I can some tutorials or documentation on interacting with Tcl databases?

Comment: For a database, use sqlite. It is a perfect companion to Tcl (the creator of sqlite is a long-time Tcl user and was a member of the Tcl core team for several years).  Plus, if you switch languages or platforms the database can still be used. See http://sqlite.com/tclsqlite.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip about sqlite.

Where is the best place to get advice or support for Tcl/tk?